# batch delete or skip the last line in for of txt

Tags: batch-file

I need to remove or skip the last line of a txt,
this is my txt

```
cod_est nro_prsna_clnte          cod_prdto                cod_sub_prdto            cod_cntto                fch_est                
------- ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ -----------------------
C                      777388304                       93                     2003             690005635930 2016-10-17 00:00:00.000

A                   910065094290                       93                     2003             690018602410 2016-10-17 00:00:00.000

A                   910065094300                       93                     2003             690018602420 2016-10-17 00:00:00.000

A                   910065094280                       93                     2003             690018602400 2016-10-17 00:00:00.000

(4 rows affected)
```

and the batch is this

```
for /F "tokens=1-6 skip=2" %%i in (OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt) do (echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n>> OFB_INF_PSN.txt)
```

the result is this

```
C,777388304,93,2003,690005635930,2016-10-17

A,910065094290,93,2003,690018602410,2016-10-17

A,910065094300,93,2003,690018602420,2016-10-17

A,910065094280,93,2003,690018602400,2016-10-17

(4,rows,affected),,,
```

but i need to delete or skip the last line  ((4,rows,affected),,,)

Can anybody help me,
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Crudely, since given the data you present is unlikely to have a missing *last wanted column) you could use

```
 for /F "tokens=1-6 skip=2" %%i in (OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt) do if "%%n" neq "" (echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n>> OFB_INF_PSN.txt)
```

where here the `"%%n"` could possibly be `"%%l%%m%%n"` to mean "each of the last 3 result columns is empty"

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to pipe the output of the file to the FIND command to find all lines that do not have the words "rows affected"

```
for /F "tokens=1-6 skip=2" %%i in ('type OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt ^|find /I /V "rows affected"') do (echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n>> OFB_INF_PSN.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general way of skipping the last line independent from its content is the following code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FILE_IN=OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt"
set "FILE_OUT=OFB_INF_PSN.txt"

rem // Redirect the entire output data once only:
> "%FILE_OUT%" (
    rem // Reset variable holding line string:
    set "LINE="
    rem // Read text file line by line:
    for /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-6" %%I in ("%FILE_IN%") do (
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Avoid output of initial empty line:
        if defined LINE (
            rem // Output previous line string:
            echo(!LINE!
        )
        endlocal
        rem // Store current line string to be output during next iteration delayed:
        set "LINE=%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M,%%N"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

This example batch file should only output the lines ending with a number:

```bat
@(For /F "Tokens=1-6" %%A In ('FindStr [0-9]$ "OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt"') Do @Echo=%%A,%%B,%%C,%%D,%%E,%%F)>"OFB_INF_PSN.txt"
```